# AngularJS: scope watch not being triggered, even with objectEquality = true

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

In my controller I have:

```
$scope.$watch('numRuns', function(newVal, oldVal) {
  if (newVal === oldVal) return;
  updateNumResults();
});

function updateNumResults() {
  $scope.resultSet.size($scope.numRuns);
  console.log("updateNumResults called");
}
```

The size method in ResultSet looks like:

```
  function size(n) {
    if (n === undefined) return numResults_; // no arg => using as getter
    numResults_ = n;
    return this;
  }
```

In my view I have:

```
Number of runs: <input ng-model="numRuns"/>
```

In my directive I have:

```
scope.$watch('resultSet', function(newVal, oldVal) {
  console.log("change in result set");
  createFromScratch();
}, true); // use object equality
```

If I type into the input box in the browser, I'll see the output "updateNumResults called", but the actual watch on `resultSet` is not called.  I have verified that the object `resultSet` is indeed getting mutated by the call to `size()`, and since I have setup the `watch` with the `objectEquality` parameter set to `true`, my understanding was that the change should be getting picked up and triggering the `watch`.  Why is that not happening and how can I make it happen?

#### UPDATE

I made the following changes to make it work:

Created a simple counter variable that I manually change each time I call any mutator method on resultSet:

```
  function updateNumResults() {
    $scope.resultSet.size($scope.numRuns);
    $scope.resultSetChanged++; 
    console.log("updateNumResults called");
  }
```

and I watch that instead in the directive:

```
  function watchResultSet() {
    scope.$watch('resultSetChanged', function(newVal, oldVal) {
      console.log("change in result set");
      createFromScratch();
    });
  }
```

This solution works fine, and is probably less resource intensive, but I would still like to know why the original solution is not working.

#### UPDATE 2 WITH JSBIN EXAMPLES

Sh0ber's idea was correct.  The problem was with private vars.

1. [JSbin using private vars (revealing module pattern) showing the problem](http://jsbin.com/oxaxab/9/edit)
2. [JSbin using normal objects works](http://jsbin.com/oxaxab/10/edit)

Comment: What have you configured the scope to be in the directive?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but the snippet I showed is from the `link(scope, elm, attrs)` method which is returned as the "link" property on the directive configuration object.

Comment: Have you configured the scope as well for your directive, or just the link function? For instance you may have scope: true, or scope:{...}

Comment: I have not specified scope, so it's using the default value.  It's reading scope just fine from the controller.

Comment: What does the `size` method look like?

Comment: It would help if you could provide the HTML that includes the `input` and the directive, and the implementation of `size()`.   Of course a minimal fiddle or plunker showing the problem would be best.

Comment: @sh0ber I updated the OP with the source of the size method

Comment: @MarkRajcok, I updated OP with the size method.  I included the relevant parts from the directive already.  But if no one is able to answer with what's given, I will try to extract the problem into a simple plunkr.

Comment: At first glance, it doesn't look like `size` mutates `resultSet`. Maybe try a plunker.

Comment: @sh0ber, the line `numResults_ = n;` changes the value of a private member var.  Does that not count as mutation?  I guess that would make sense, actually.  If it doesn't, go ahead and put that as an answer.

Comment: @MarkRajcok, I just added two simple JSbins demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is based on some discussion in the question:

This code *will* work if the `resultSet` object is mutated.  After looking at the `size` method it appeared to only be altering some private vars in `resultSet`'s constructor. The `resultSet` object itself was not changing and so the `$watch` was never triggered.

Comment: sh0ber, thank you!  i've updated the OP with corrected links and credited your idea for the problem with the private vars.  You may want to update this answer with your old one about the private vars, just to avoid future confusion, and then I'll accept it.

Comment: thanks.  i edited out the last part since it doesn't apply now that i've fixed the links in the OP which show the test cases for your correct hypothesis

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you've configured your directive to have a separate isolated scope (you've passed a hash to the scope parameter). Since you have configured the watching in the scope of the directive, you need to make sure this scope is the same as the controllers scope, or inherits it.

Read the [Angular guide on directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) (especially on the scope configuration) for more information.

Comment: @Jonah - this answer may be useful for someone in the future. In general, I don't recommend that OPs request answer deletion, unless an answer should have been a comment or is highly off-topic.

Comment: @halfer, This answer should have been comment.  It is a guess about something that it turns out is not at all relevant to my question.  When such answers are given, especially as a first answer, they detract from traffic to the question that may result in a legitmate answer.

Comment: I'd say it's too substantial for a comment, though I don't know the topic. But, be nice to your interlocutors - in general they are only trying to help!

Comment: @halfer, When was I not nice?  I politely asked him to delete the question after explaining why his answer wasn't relevant.  I am very appreciative of all the help I get on here, even the help that doesn't work out.  But my main goal is still to get a correct answer and this answer was counterproductive to that goal.